# Cannot create noindexed columns with in sqlite FTS table

Tags: sql, sqlite, full-text-search, fts4

I'm trying to create the following table with **sqlite 3.8.2**

```
    CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS media_fts
        USING fts4 (
            notindexed=media_id,
            notindexed=album_id,
            title,
            artist,
            album_artist,
            album,
            comment,
            lyrics
        ) ;
```

But some reason, the command fails with the following error:

```
 no such column: media_id
```

Do you know what is going wrong?

> Note : According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18531449/740464), `notindexed` is supported for 3.8 and above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `notindexed=` option is not a column but just an option.
So when you want an unindexed column, you still have to list the column itself:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS media_fts
    USING fts4 (
        title,
        artist,
        album_artist,
        album,
        comment,
        lyrics,
        media_id,
        album_id,
        notindexed=media_id,
        notindexed=album_id
    ) ;
```